# Sort words in file

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting, sort

I’ve got some problems I’m not capable of overcoming. I need to count the first let's say N words in a text file. Then, I have to print them in decreasing order, followed by the number of occurrences.The words must be sorted alphabetically.

As an example , if I have 6 occurrences of word "**a**" , 5 of word **"b"**, 5 of word **c** and n is given as 2, I’ll print:

**a 6**

**b 5**

If I have 10 occurrences of word "la" , 5 of word "hi" , 5 of "zzz" and 5 of "arr", and n given as 3 , I’ll print:

**la 10**

**arr 5**

**hi 5**

(the zzz is omitted intentionally).

The problem is that my script (which is below) only prints one word of each number of occurrences.

```
tr  [:space:] '\n' <$1| uniq -c|sort -rnuk1,1|awk '{print $2,$1}'|head -n
```

As an extra feature, I’d like the script to search number of occurrences of words in the first m lines of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `tr` is clever. But you need to `sort` before you use `uniq`, because `uniq` only looks at adjacent lines. So we have

```
cat file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | awk '{print $2, $1}' | head -n 10
```

Also as you can see the use of `-k` and `-n` for sort is unnecessary in this case (though not wrong).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the first question would be (if anyone is interested ?)

```
tr  [:space:] '\n' <$1| sort |uniq -c|sort -k1rn -k2n|awk '{print $2,$1}'|head -12
```

I still don't know how to do this part .

> As an extra feature , i'd like the script to seach number of
>   occurencies of words in the first m lines of file.

Comment: `head -n 10` will give you the first 10 lines of a file; that may help you solve the extra piece

Comment: But what about if let's say i need to print the words that have more than x apperances ?

Comment: If you've sorted and uniq -c'd, then one way would be to use awk to ask if field 2 is greater than X

Comment: @JeffSchaller ok , but if X is a parameter given as an input?

Comment: Search this site for ways that people pass variables into awk. Look for -v